# Angular, BsDatepicker Format

Tags: angular

I hope everyone is okay, I am new to angular so I have a problem with this input, it's working fine but  always returns the error:
`Property 'startDate' does not exist on type 'AddComponent'`, but it exists in the component

**This is for componenent.html**

`<form [formGroup]= "parentForm" (submit) = "persistEvent()"> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="startDate" id="startDate" formControlName="startDate" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="startDate" value="{{ startDate.value | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"   > </form>`

**This is for componenent.ts**

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'app-add',
    templateUrl: './add.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
})


   export class AddComponent implements OnInit { 
   constructor( 
   private fb: FormBuilder
   ) { }

   parentForm: FormGroup;

   this.parentForm = this.fb.group({
     startDate: new FormControl('', [
       Validators.required
     ]) })
 }
```

Comment: We'll need to see the components code as well. In particular we need to see how you initialize the form.

Comment: Thank you for your reply i edited the post